# Magick++ - Unable to open image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, imagemagick

I am trying to read an in image using a simple example from Magick++:

```
Magick::Image image;
try {
    // Read a file into image object 
    image.read("C:\\Pictures\\lena.jpg");

    // Crop the image to specified size (width, height, xOffset, yOffset)
    image.crop(Magick::Geometry(100, 100, 100, 100));

    // Write the image to a file 
    image.write("C:\\Pictures\\lenaCropped.jpg");
}
catch (Magick::Exception &error_)
{
    std::cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```

This fails and throws an exception:

> Unable to open image: No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3109

And if I change `C:\\Pictures\\lena.jpg` to `C:/Pictures/lena.jpg` it throws another exception:

> Unable to open image: Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3109

Of course the image path is correct.

Comment: Do you get the same error message when running from CLI? `magick C:\\Pictures\\lena.jpg -crop 100x100+100+100 C:\\Pictures\\lenaCropped.jpg`

Comment: I do not know Magick++ or Windows, but it looks like it cannot find your file. Are the double \\ really necessary. Should they not be single \ as in image.read("C:\Pictures\lena.jpg");

Comment: Also try the [Raw literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). `image.read(R"(C:\Pictures\lena.jpg)");`

Comment: @emcconville 1) Running from CLI (console magick.exe) works just fine (same image path). 2) Raw literal still fails.

Comment: @fmw42 You can write `"C:\\Pictures\\lena.jpg"` or `"C:/Pictures/lena.jpg"` or `R"(C:\Pictures\lena.jpg)"`

Comment: If you can, try upgrading to the latest Visual Studio. I half remember some STL changes, but I'm simply not around window machines to identify.